# Convert object key to lowercase

Tags: c#, string

With C# how can I ensure the 'val' object in the code below is lowercase?

```
case MultiValueUpdateMode.AddIfNotExist:
if (value != null)
{
    // Add the values only if they do not exist
    foreach (var val in newValues)
    {
        if (!userDe.Properties["proxyAddresses"].Contains(val))
        userDe.Properties["proxyAddresses"].Add(val);
    }
}
break;
```

Comment: You didn't give us enough information, but you can use ToLower() extension method for strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert ***any*** object to the string by using `ToString()` then use `ToLower()` to make it lower-cased string:

```
string lowerCasedString = val?.ToString()?.ToLower(); //put null coaelescing just in case it is null
```

Then use it like this:

```
if (!userDe.Properties["proxyAddresses"].Contains(lowerCasedString))
```

Additional note: I normally would also remove the leading and following white-spaces by using `Trim()`:

```
string cleanLowerCasedString = val?.ToString()?.ToLower()?.Trim(); //put null coaelescing just in case it is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
case MultiValueUpdateMode.AddIfNotExist:
if (value != null)
  {
    // Add the values only if they do not exist
    foreach (var val in newValues)
    {
        var  lowerCaseVal =  val.ToLower();
        if (!userDe.Properties["proxyAddresses"].Contains(lowerCaseVal))
        userDe.Properties["proxyAddresses"].Add(lowerCaseVal);
    }
  }
break;
```

Comment: When I add val =  val.ToLower(); where you suggested I get the intellisense error 'Cannot assign to 'val' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'. Am I missing something else?

Comment: @user1226884 Updated . Thanks